# Will RxJS forkJoin return results in order?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

RxJS provides a function called `forkJoin`. It allows you to input multiple `Observables` and wait for all of them to finish. I am wondering if the resulting array will contain the results in the same order as the order of the input observables. If it wil not, which one of the operators does maintain the same order? I've been looking into the [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) and was not able to find the answer.

Comment: yes, it will be in the same order

Comment: Just went through the official documentation (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin). Yes it will be in the same order.

Comment: The documentations says following :  "forkJoin will wait for all passed Observables to complete and then it will emit an array with last values from corresponding Observables. So if you pass n Observables to the operator, resulting array will have n values, where first value is the last thing emitted by the first Observable, second value is the last thing emitted by the second Observable and so on."

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It will return results in the same order. As is described in [these official docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin).

Good to mention that it will emit only latest values of the streams:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
  Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3),
  Rx.Observable.of(4)
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log("Result", x));

// LOG: Result [3,4]
```

Comment: this is the right kind of answer which gives example and link to documentation

Answer (score 6):

## Anti-answer

For this of us who actually want to get results sorted by task finish time you can use following alternative to forkJoin

```js
const { merge, of } = rxjs;
const { bufferCount, take, delay } = rxjs.operators;

let t1 = of(1).pipe(delay(1000));
let t2 = of(2).pipe(delay(3000));
let t3 = of(3).pipe(delay(4000));
let t4 = of(4).pipe(delay(2000));

// in forkJoin(t1,t2,t3,t4) we get:      [1,2,3,4]
// in this we get sorted by finish time: [1,4,2,3]
// bufferCount(4) join 4 results to array
// take(1) take one buffer and unsubscribe after

merge(t1,t2,t3,t4)
  .pipe(bufferCount(4), take(1))      
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```